# 2 versions of cordova-ios: v5.* and v6.* have different screen sizes even though tested on 1 device

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I added and compared 2 versions of cordova-ios: v5.1.1 and v6.0.0 on same device: ipad pro 10.5
And I can see the difference in app size between v5.1.1 (768x1024) & v6.0.0 (834x1112)

[v5_1_1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICuY2.png)

[v6_0_0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0CyP.png)

So my questions are:

1. why is there a difference in this app screen size?
2. is there a way to fix the size  768X1024 for v6.0.0?